# What's the condition for (x+kp) and pq being coprime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Suppose $p$ and $q$  are large primes and $N=pq$.

$x$ is an arbitrary integer in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $k$ is a random integer.

Then what is the condition for $k$ (suppose $x$ is fixed) such that $(x+kp)$  and $N=pq$ are coprime?

Comment: We need $(x,p)=1, (x+kp,q)=1$

Comment: Yes. Since $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p$, we get $(x,p)=1$. Then what's the condition for $k$ such that $(x+kp,q)=1$? More specifically, can we express the condition for $k$  in terms of $x,p,q$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $p$ and $q$ are prime, a number $n$ is coprime to $N$ if and only if $n\ne 0\ (\ mod\ p)$ and $n\ne 0\ (\ mod\ q)$. It is easy to see that $x+kp\ne 0\ (\ mod \ p\ )$ is equivalent to $x\ne 0\ (\ mod\ p\ )$. If this does not hold, $x+pq$ cannot be coprime to $N$. The other condition is simply $x+kp\ne 0\ (\ mod\ q\ )$, giving $k\ne -xp^{-1}\ (\ mod\ q\ )$, where $p^{-1}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $p$ in $\mathbb Z_q$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is right to me.